# ElasticBeanstalk: Environment in an unhealthy state(Codeship Pro, Jets)

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, codeship

I am trying to deploy a django app using Codeship Pro to Elasticbeans talk(using docker of course). Running this step fails when when deploying

> codeship-steps.yml:

```
- name: deployment
      tag: aws-docker
      service: awsdeployment
      command: codeship_aws eb_deploy ./deploy my-project staging my-bucket
```

---

> docker-compose.yml

```
    services:

      app:...
      db:...

      awsdeployment:
        image: codeship/aws-deployment
        encrypted_env_file: aws-deployment.env.encrypted
        environment:
          - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
        volumes:
          - ./:/deploy
```

Error:

[image]
Info: I am trying to setup a CI/CD environment for the project(staging/production env)

UPDATE: in my elasticbeanstalk, I see that the django extension is not found although I have made they are installed in my Dockerfile.(`pip install -r requirements.txt`)